# How to avoid text color to change on UIButton selection with selectors on UIControlEvents?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How to avoid text color to change on UIButton selection with selectors on UIControlEvents ?

I am trying to make sure that the text color of my button doesn't change when it's higlighted, selected or normal. Because of my selector, it is not working. I have also tried changing the titleLabel's text color in the selectors but it didn't work. As you can see I need to change the backgroundcolor when it's highlited... Adding control events target is the only way I found to change the background color on selection.

Here is my button configuration code :

```
func setBtn(btn: UIButton) {
    setBtnTarget(btn)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState:  UIControlState.Highlighted )
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
}

func setBtnTarget(btn: UIButton) {
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "highlighted:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "normal:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

func highlighted(btn : UIButton) {
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0.133, blue:0.229, alpha:1)
}
func normal(btn : UIButton) {
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0.058, blue:0.099, alpha:1)
}
```

Any other working alternatives are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you really want a button?  Looks like you can do all of what you need with an interactive label

Comment: yes I really need a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems good, you just need to make sure that your button type is custom.

```
let btn = UIButton(type: .Custom)
```

Comment: Nailed it. exactly what I was looking for.